# Add warning message for answers being edited from the LQP queue

Tags: feature-request, review, low-quality-posts

Recently came across a [NAA post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53323390/4875631), and flagged it as such:

[image]

While it was in the queue, it was edited out of the queue, and still remained a question, and thus needed to be manually flagged to the ♦ mods for removal. This is a common problem among the [NATO team](https://stackapps.com/questions/7049/natty-bringing-10k-moderation-to-all), who usually [edit posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375905/possible-bot-idea-should-1-off-bad-reviews-in-first-post-late-post-queue-be-rep#comment642221_375905) beforehand in order to prevent edits like these. I'd like to try and prevent these incorrect edits from ever happening. I suggest a message similar to below, when a user attempts to edit a question in the LQP queue, that has been marked as NAA (Maybe perhaps the first few edits only):

> **WAIT!** You are attempting to edit an answer that has been flagged as "Not an Answer". If you're unable to edit this into an *answer*, this post should be flagged for deletion instead.

Comment: I would use word "Wait" instead of "Stop"

Comment: Well, technically, if an answer is edited outside of the queue, it only gets removed if the new revision passes the system's quality test.

Comment: This is also similar to a very similar request I made a while ago asking for a warning on questions undergoing reopen review, or have been closed within the last five days, since such minor edits don't affect the reopenability (or not) yet reviewers are still shown the diff, so they tend to disagree with reopening even though the question itself is reopenable.